# Error deserialising LocalDateTime in POST request

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I have a class which contains two LocalDateTime members:

```
public class Foo
{
    private final LocalDateTime start;
    private final LocalDateTime end;

    public Foo(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

I have a Spring Boot controller to handle a POST request:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/my-resource")
public ResponseEntity<?> bar(@RequestBody Foo foo)
{
   return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

If I send a POST request as follows:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/my-resource \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "start":[2016, 1, 1, 10, 24],
    "end":[2016, 1, 1, 10, 24]
}
'
```

the following error is returned:

```
"message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class Foo]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `Foo` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 2]"
```

After some digging around I added a default ctor to Foo and that resolved the error. I also had to remove `final` from the members.

I don't understand why this solution works. Can someone explain this?

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson, https://www.baeldung.com/jackson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson uses reflection to instantiate the `Foo` class and this mechanism requires the existence of a default constructor.

**After** instantiating the `Foo` class, using reflection again, Jackson will set the field values of that instance - currently all field values are null. Since you declared those fields `final` it fails to modify them.

Here is an example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Reflection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Child.class;
            Object child = clazz.newInstance();
            Field f1 = child.getClass().getDeclaredField("age");

            // Because 'age' field is private
            // we make it accesible
            f1.setAccessible(true);

            // Set the desired value
            f1.set(child, 10);
            System.out.println("Child: " + child);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Child {
    private int age;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Child [age=" + age + "]";
    }

}
```

The Jackson's serialization/deserialization mechanism is very flexible. There are lots of annotations you can set and configuration you can make.

Here is another example:

```
public class Jackson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String jsonAsString = "{\"age\":10}";
            Child child = mapper.readValue(jsonAsString, Child.class);
            System.out.println(child);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above example doesn't work because `age` field doesn't have accessor methods. To overcome this, we can add:

```
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

and the above example will be working now.

Very good documentation about Jackson can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) as @JB Nizet pointed out in a comment.

Comment: So how does Jackson modify the fields if they are private and there are no setters?

Comment: @ksl Private fields can be modified using reflection, assuming  no SecurityManager is preventing this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply annotate the constructor with [`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html):

```
@JsonCreator
public Foo(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}
```

Once your dates use *a very particular format*, you'll need to write a custom deserializer to handle them.

---

If you stick to [ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/), you can rely on the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html): It will provide you with a set of [serializers](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/package-summary.html) and [deserializers](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/package-summary.html) for [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) [datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html).

See details [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime).

Comment: So, annotating the ctor in this way means I don't need a default ctor? Is this a preferred way to implement it?

Comment: @ksl Jackson won't need a default constructor if you use `@JsonCreator`.